# Keyup prevent default not working angular6

Tags: javascript, angular6, keydown, keyup

I want to stop entering any number after validating a custom regular expression , the issue is condition got true but event.preventDefault is not preventing the input , The reg ex is to input value in percentage between 1-100 with decimals

```
/^(100(\.0{1,2})?|[1-9]?\d(\.\d{1,2})?)$/
```

this is my input

```
<input  type='text' (keyup)="preventPercentage($event)"  [(ngModel)]="value">
```

**ts**

```
preventPercentage(event){
  var p = event.target.value
  var s= p.match(/^(100(\.0{1,2})?|[1-9]?\d(\.\d{1,2})?)$/)  != null
  if(!s && p){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

user can still enter any value even  the condition is true
input anything between 100 above it still working and event is not preventing values

```
  <input  type='text' (keydown)="preventPercentage($event)"  [(ngModel)]="value">
```

I used key down but it allows to enter 123 i.e three digit numbers
and I cannot then remove that number using backspace what exactly I am doing wrong can anyone suggest a sol any help will be appreciated

Comment: Just a wild card. Add event.stopPropagation() and return false.

Comment: @EdwinDijasChiwona not working

Comment: Use all three. event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); event.stopImmediatePropagation();

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think there is a change required in the regex as per your requirement.

```
preventPercentage(event){
  var p = event.target.value + event.key;
  var s = p.match(/^(100(\.0{1,2})?|[1-9]?\d(\.\d{1,2})?)$/) != null;
  if (!s && event.keyCode !== 8) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Use this with keydown:

```
<input  type='text' (keydown)="preventPercentage($event)" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

Comment: not working, comparing with event key only is invalid

Comment: I have updated with some changes in script, I think this regex is not working in angular as expected

Comment: @KumailHussain
please check another answer that I have posted, there was a problem with regex execution as I was telling you from starting. I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

```
preventPercentage(event: any) {
      function stopProgram() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      }
      if (event.keyCode === 8) {
        return true;
      }
      var p = event.target.value;
      if ((event.keyCode === 190 && p.indexOf('.') > -1) || p === '100') {
        return stopProgram();
      }
      p = p + event.key;
      var s = p.match(/^(100(\.0{1,2})?|[1-9]?\d(\.\d{1,2})?)$/) != null;
      if (!s && event.keyCode !== 190) {
        return stopProgram();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's necessary to use `keydown` event, not `keyup`.

It considers that the keyboard action is already done and you cannot cancel it.